# How do I make a Kindle 3G into a monitor using Ubuntu?

Tags: kindle

Is there a guide for Linux step by step? I want to use my Kindle as a secondary monitor with a clone image of what is happening at the main PC.

I have jail breaked the Kindle. And I also think I got the USB network setup.

Addition for clarification:

I am pretty sure its possible to run it with Windows according to this manual.
I basically wanna do the same thing but using Ubuntu as indicated in this [article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/259582/how_to_use_a_kindle_dx_as_a_pc_display.html).

I'm stuck at the place where I have to make the USB networking work. 
I have downloaded Tight VNC Server but cant find the Kindle's IP address.

Comment: Is this even possible? Do you have anything that imply's this can be done?  The issue IMO is that a kindle is an e-reader with a special display, I don't see how this could be possible.

Comment: What do you want? Install Ubuntu on the e-reader? Use the e-reader instead of a monitor for your existing Ubuntu?

Comment: You say you jailbroke your Kindle, which means it probably isn't a Kindle Fire (that'd be rooting), which means it has an E-Ink display. Even if it were possible (which I guess technically it is, but I don't think it's been done), E-Ink is not mean to act as a computer monitor. The experience would be terrible and mostly useless.

Comment: @guntbert wrote :
"What do you want? Install Ubuntu on the e-reader? Use the e-reader instead of a monitor for your existing Ubuntu?" 

Yes. Use the e-reader instead of a monitor for your existing Ubuntu

Comment: I cant find the Ip adress of the kindle, so I canuse tightvnc server

Comment: I read the PCWorld article you linked to, and voted to reopen your question.

Comment: _What_ kind of Kindle do you have? That article is specific to the Kindle DX.

Comment: Yes I have a kindle 3g the USA version wifi and 3g , serial number B006A0A01045157p

Comment: I will make an other question, and start an other thread and be more specific. I will post a link to it afterwards